# Lubuntu 18:10: Failed to execute child process "lxsession-default" (No such file or > directory)

Tags: lubuntu, filemanager

My lubunutu is installed in a virtual machine. Whenever I try to open the file manager from taskbar icon nothing happens. If I try to open the file manager from desktop options I get this message

> Failed to execute child process "lxsession-default" (No such file or
>   directory)

BTW my desktop options also changed. Previously clicking right mouse button would let me access options such as change background etc. now they are missing and replaced with open file manager, multimedia etc. My desktop background is now blank.

Comment: Can you please add the command and messages to your question.  The default file manager in Lubuntu 18.04 & before was `pcmanfm`, with `pcmanfm-qt` replacing it from Lubuntu 18.10 and up. Which are you trying to run?  and neither is called pacman (*it's the name of a package manager used by arch linux*). What right-click on desktop does is controlled by your openbox settings (check them) & desktop preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've edited the question

Comment: Is this a clean install or an upgrade from Lubuntu 18.04?

Comment: What do you see when you run `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` from a terminal?

Comment: it was a clean install. I get this "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXQt
"

Comment: Comment added long after:  `lxsession` is LXDE and a clean Lubuntu with LXQt install has no references to LXDE programs; so my guess is you upgraded your system without re-install as recommended, eg. Lubuntu 19.04 & later release notes state clearly "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10's release notes (https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-released/) were less clear, "*The most major and notable problem is that upgrading Lubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 causes a fair amount of issues. Therefore, we are not officially supporting this upgrade path at this time, however we have prepared a page in the Lubuntu Manual which can help address the problems that arise after the upgrade.*" which initially linked to a page which provided fixes. Users had issues with this and were still seeking support, so the page was removed (page is now generic upgrades, not LXDE->LXQt)

Comment: the LXDE->LXQt detail was still present on Lubuntu's infrastructure (phab) or it was, but it requires searching as it's no longer published anywhere (ie. it's commits & diffs of changes only that last remained of it)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What resolve the issue for me was to open LXQT settings then Desktop. Click on advanced tab and uncheck "show menus provided by windows managers when desktop is clicked" under Window Manager.

Lubuntu 19.10