# desktop won't work on lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, openbox

Alright so, I was playing around with PHP in atom while using local by flywheel and Firefox open, I was using about 1.5 GB of RAM (there was other stuff open), but anyways, I decided to change my background to something I downloaded earlier.

So I went to desktop settings and changed it, pressed apply and next thing you know, the desktop settings froze, it asked me of I wanted to kill it so I killed it, I tried navigating in my desktop but nothing worked, the desktop is blank, I tried going to the file manager but it wouldn't open, so any ideas?

I have been using Lubuntu for the past week now and I'm happy I switched to it, it can't be ruined now! Oh yeah and also, when I try opening desktop settings it would say:

```
failed to execute child process lxsession-default directory (no such file or directory)
```

And it would also leave a trace behind the window or whatever. Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbvFA.png).

---

**Edit**: The trace behind the window happens with all apps open, not only the one shown in the image.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108134/discussion-on-question-by-spangbab-desktop-wont-work-on-lubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone hay this problem in the future:

To get a clear vision of the problem i saw one possible solution here:

[Lubuntu 18:10: Failed to execute child process "lxsession-default" (No such file or > directory)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144623/lubuntu-1810-failed-to-execute-child-process-lxsession-default-no-such-file)

By the way, the most easy way to solve it is **format the Linux partitions**(we tried other ways but looks imposible, he cant use the lxqt control pannel either).

**Actualization:** I found the way to enter the Desktop configuration menu to apply the solution in the mentioned link:

You should log off, and then log in using the Openbox Desktop Enviroment. When u are inside it(sometimes you need to do right click on the screen, because it looks like the login screen), you should open a terminal emulator and apply this commands:

```
cd /usr/bin/
```

And after that:

```
lxqt-config
```

(sometimes you could skip the 1st command and launch the application directly, without using the cd command)

Once there, you should choose the icon(it will not have icon) "Desktop".
After that you could go to the tab called "advanced" and then unmark(disable) the option called:
"Show menus provided by windows managers when desktop is clicked"

If someone tries this method descripted in the actualization and it works, **please comment this answer**, so if anyone more have the problem he could apply this solution too.

This second option is thanks to "**taos001**"(He posted it in one answer of the link provided here)

Comment: What does "format the SO" mean?

Comment: That really doesn't mean anything, you can't format an OS. Do you mean you formatted the partition it was installed on and reinstalled it?

Comment: Yes, i mean that, format the disk to reinstall you linux distribution. Just edited it again, so it have more sense

Comment: Wow, that's quite a solution.

Comment: We tried find other ways, but he cant launch the lxqt config applets, he reinstalled pcmanfm-qt too, but that doenst worked either

Comment: sadly enough yes

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution provided by taos001 at https://askubuntu.com/a/1200652/1559256 worked for me using Lubuntu 20.04

1. Go to LXQt Configuration Centre
2. Click "Desktop"
3. Click "Advanced"
4. Uncheck "Show menus provided by windows managers when desktop is clicked"